# Margin issue between Safari and Firefox

Tags: firefox, safari, margins

Here is the site that is having the issue: http://newcombspring.stifel-marcin.com/

The portion of the site which is having the issue is the 'FORMING THE FUTURE' div. When viewing the site in Safari it is aligned perfectly but when viewing it in Firefox you can see that it is moved over to the right just a few pixels. What could be causing this and how can it easily be solved?

Comment: it's worth saying I'm looking at it in Chrome, and it doesn't look right either.

Comment: by the way: I notice you're using a background graphic for the gradient on that div. have you considered using a CSS gradient instead?

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any margins involved here. The problem you are having here is basically all being caused by the fact that you're using tables for your layout. The simple fact is that tables are not recommended for this kind of thing.

I actually really like what you've done here. The design is great. But the underlying HTML structure isn't so great. You can tweak it all you like, and you might even come close to solving the problem, but as long as you have your layout created using tables, you're never going to be truly free of this kind of issue.

Unfortunately, I can't really offer much of a solution here, beyond scrapping a large part of your page body, and re-doing it using a more structured layout.

I don't have the time to go into a lot of detail about how to do that, but I suggest looking up [tableless design](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=tableless+design+tutorial).

The good news is that the basic two-panel layout you've created here can be done really easily with relatively little code using a good tableless design.

I know that isn't the quick and simple answer you were looking for, but I hope it helps.